# alignment of single element inside div with display: flex;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my html and css below

```
    .flex {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .my-btn {
        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #3f729b;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    <div class="flex">
        <span class="my-btn btn-back">back</span>

        <span class="my-btn btn-download">download</span>

        <span class="my-btn btn-next">next</span>
    </div>
```

if all the `.my-btn` are visible, everything is looking fine, but if I want to have only `.btn-next` visible it is left aligned. How can I have it right aligned. I've tried to use

```
.btn-next {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

but it's not working.

And ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/ahzc1f41/1/

Comment: Can you do this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/374/?

Comment: I don't want to do that trick with opacity. I've just added jsfiddle link to my question.

Comment: I am using Angular.js (ng-show)

Comment: You can do this with flexbox `auto` margins. See here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 3):

Add `margin-left: auto;` to your .btn-back. That's how it's meant to be done

EDIT: Add `margin-right: auto;` to `btn-back` and `margin: 0 auto;` to `btn-download` because when the one of the other buttons are shown, it fails without.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/2x36vuch/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="flex">
    <span class="my-btn btn-back">back</span>

    <span class="my-btn btn-download">download</span>

    <span class="my-btn btn-next">next</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.my-btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3f729b;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-next {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.btn-download{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn-back{
  margin-right: auto;
}

.btn-download, .btn-back {
  //display: none;      
}
```

SOURCE: http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Comment: Yep...you might want to update the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/2x36vuch/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin-left: auto;` on `.btn-next` and `margin-right: auto;` on `.btn-back`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ahzc1f41/5/)**

```css
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.my-btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3f729b;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-next {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.btn-back {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.btn-download, .btn-back {
  display: none;      
}
```

```html
    <div class="flex">
        <span class="my-btn btn-back">back</span>

        <span class="my-btn btn-download">download</span>

        <span class="my-btn btn-next">next</span>
    </div>
```